# Tensorflow: The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorboard, amazon-machine-learning

Each time I'm trying to train and evaluate my tensorflow training set on the Cloud platform, the job terminates midway showing this error.

Given below is the error message I had received:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Termination 
reason: Error. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] File 
"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/object_detection/evaluator.py", line 132, in evaluate 
ignore_groundtruth=eval_config.ignore_groundtruth) File 
"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/object_detection/evaluator.py", line 51, in 
_extract_prediction_tensors input_dict = create_input_dict_fn() File 
"/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/object_detection/builders/input_reader_builder.py", line 61, 
in build min_after_dequeue=input_reader_config.min_after_dequeue) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/parallel_reader.py", 
line 234, in parallel_read 
reader_kwargs=reader_kwargs).read(filename_queue) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/parallel_reader.py", 
line 132, in read 
enqueue_ops.append(self._common_queue.enqueue(reader.read(queue))) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 191, in read return 
gen_io_ops._reader_read_v2(self._reader_ref, queue_ref, name=name) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 410, in 
_reader_read_v2 queue_handle=queue_handle, name=name) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in 
apply_op op_def=op_def) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op 
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def) File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__ 
self._traceback = _extract_stack() UnimplementedError (see above for 
traceback): File system scheme sgs not implemented [[Node: 
parallel_read/ReaderReadV2 = 
ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2, parallel_read/filenames)]]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should format your log better. Few are going to read that mess.

Comment: Could you share you pipeline config?